# What is Spock's full name?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, spock

What is Spock's full, allegedly unpronounceable name?  (And no, I don't mean Dr. Benjamin McLane Spock.  I mean the son of Sarek.)

Comment: I am pretty certain it has never been put into print anywhere.

Comment: +1, but is there a reference that states that he had a "full, **allegedly unpronounceable** name?"? Just curious.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To in TOS:This Side of Paradise, Spock told Leila Kalomi that she "couldn't pronounce it."

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Spock's full name is **[S'chn T'gai Spock](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Spock)**.

[From memory-beta:](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Spock)

> Spock's full name was revealed in TOS novel: *Ishmael*. In TOS episode:
>   "This Side of Paradise", Spock said that his full name was
>   unpronounceable to Humans.

It is revealed in a TOS novel called *Ishmael*.

Apart from this reference, and the name being deemed unpronounceable in a TOS episode, there is no real proof of his name ever being said in a canonical reference (to my knowledge).

Comment: It is a non-canon source. It is a good find, (I have the novel) but I assumed we were working on a canon reference...

Comment: @Thaddeus: I was also wondering about canon. What makes this source in or out of canon?

Comment: Thanks -- now I know.  Of course, I am guaranteed to be pronouncing it wrong ...

Comment: @Wikis AFAIK the only "official" canon in Star Trek are the live-action television series and movies. (The animated series seems to be making a canon-come back, though.) There used to be a FAQ on the Paramount site about this, but it has been removed.

Comment: @Wikis - as Michael said, books are officially NOT considered Star Trek canon. You can see that specifically by which site the reference came from: Memory-Alpha is TV/Movie canon, Memory-Beta is non-canon books. AFAIK there's a third "fanfic" Memory* site as well

Comment: Thanks, all. @DVK: ah, I wondered what the alpha / beta distinction was...

Comment: @DVK I think that would be [Memory Gamma](http://memory-gamma.wikia.com/wiki/Portal:Main), which is just on Wikia, it doesn't have its own domain.

Comment: @Wikis Also, on Memory Alpha, there's several articles that have an "Apocrypha" section for non-canon information - generally stuff that came from the novels.

Comment: So could it also be argued that his FULL name would be "S'chn T'gai Spock Grayson?

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Based on some of the crazy whacked out things I've read on Memory-Beta, I consider the books nothing more than fan fiction.

Comment: Before someone mentions the Strange New Worlds character poster, CBS confirmed that was a mistake, and that is not his name.

Answer (score 6):

According to Memory Alpha:

> Jane Wyatt, who played Spock's mother Amanda Grayson, was once asked by fans at a convention what Spock's first name was. She replied, perhaps jokingly, "Harold". [11] However, the question itself was flawed, since the episode "Journey to Babel" makes it clear that "Spock" is Spock's personal name.
>
> On the other hand, Spock's family name has never been established in canon. In the episode "This Side of Paradise", Leila Kalomi says to Spock, "You never told me if you had another name," to which he replies, "You couldn't pronounce it." D.C. Fontana – who was considered the "Vulcan expert" of the TOS behind-the-scenes staff and who created such details as the fact that Spock's father was an ambassador and his mother a school teacher – revealed, in an issue of the fanzine Spockanalia, that she had intended his family name to be "Xtmprsqzntwlfd", but since this is unpronounceable, there wasn't really any way to get this said in dialogue during an episode.

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spock[1]

In fact I remember some publication in which Spock was Spock's middle name.

His full name was something like Xantksisk Spock Xtmprsqzntwlfd.  But we would have to look up whatever publication that was to find out how it was spelled.

Combining that with S'chn T'gai Spock would make a name that would be a real mouthful.

Answer (score -2):

Willam Shatner wrote a book about Star Trek academy. We can safely assume this book is canonical. It is S'chn T'gai.

Comment: Only the live-action TV series and movies are canonical (and The Animated Series debatable).  All the Star Trek novels are considered non-canon.

Answer (score -4):

I view Trek Books as canon. And yes, I too have maintained Spock's first name as being S'chn T'gai. SOme nut said his first name was Ed. Allegedly named after his maternal grandfather in the book Spock's World.

Comment: Sorry, but Trek's books aren't canon.  Paramount gets to decide what is/isn't canon, and they don't include the books.

Comment: HAhahah, Ed Spock!

Comment: The books frequently contradict each other, do they not? (Even more than the series, that is.)

Comment: Isn't his first name "doctor"?

Comment: @zipquincy... there is only one man in the universe with the name doctor. WHOVIANS UNITE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! And with that said its Spock O'Clock

Comment: @giacomocasanova And just **who** would that man be?

Comment: Never understood why people insist on calling him "Doctor Spock"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [this guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Common_Sense_Book_of_Baby_and_Child_Care) had the existing 'cultural capital' for the name.