# Why is Tuvok so accepting of others calling him by his first name?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, starfleet-rank

As Tuvok is Vulcan, I would think that he'd view basically everything in light of Starfleet guidelines, including how subordinates address him. However, he is apparently okay with Harry Kim and Tom Paris, for example, calling him by his first name. This is the case even though the two are of lower rank and sometimes obnoxious.

Is there a canon reason why Tuvok doesn't ride them (and other subordinates) for not addressing him as "Sir" or "Lieutenant"?

Comment: Perhaps insisting on being addressed by rank unnecessarily is illogical...

Comment: @colmde I have some recollection (not 100%) of Spock insisting on being addressed by rank by subordinates in one episode of TOS. But those were special circumstances.

Comment: Well, *Voyager* is a unique place compared to other Starfleet ships. It would probably be unsustainable if Janeway insisted on military rigor for possibly 70 years.

Comment: To clarify - The title seems like the question is about calling him Tuvok, rather than using some sort of Vulcan surname; however, the body of the question is about calling him *by name* rather than *by rank or some similar honorific, e.g. "sir"*.Perhaps the titel should be changed to "...calling him by name"?

Comment: They also call him "Mr. Tuvok" a lot.

Comment: “Mr. Tuvok” is at least respectful. And Captain Janeway and Chakotay can address Tuvok any way they please. I don’t recall Paris or Kim ever referring to the Vulcan in this way, though. Perhaps in Season 1.

Comment: I mean, if he’s cool with Mr Vulcan, this really isn’t surprising.

Answer (score 27):

As far as I'm aware, Vulcans only have one name, or at least one commonly used name. Spock, for instance, was simply Commander Spock. T'Pol was simply (Sub-)Commander T'Pol.

Generally speaking, it seems that Starfleet protocol is that in the case of officers with only one name (Tuvok, Worf, Data) it is not seen as overly familiar to use their one name as though it was a last name.

As for why *Tuvok specifically* doesn't make a fuss about it, well, Vulcans are used to meeting the illogical behavior of their comrades - especially human ones - with stoicism.

Comment: This does not address being "addressed by a **subordinate**". Convention (if not regulation) in branches of the US military, from which Star Trek draws a *lot* of influence, is: with *subordinates* around you call *peers* and *superiors* by **Rank *and* Name**, when *subordinates* aren't around, **first** name or **last** name is okay for *peers*. *Supervisors* are addressed by **Rank** or **Rank and Name** (addressing by rank alone is often reserved for general officers, Rank and Name is "by the book") or **Sir**, not just **Name**. Kim and Paris are in breach of regulations and good manners.

Comment: @Smartybartfast maybe that's why Kim never gets a promotion.

Comment: @OrangeDog Yeah, and Paris got busted out of a Penal Colony, he's not exactly what you'd call a "by the book" kind of guy.

Comment: IIRC there was a scene in in TOS where Spock said that he has a last name, but it can't be pronounced by humans. But as with so many details in Star Trek, later writers might have forgotten about this.

Comment: @Philipp : Or perhaps not forgotten, but discarded out of practical necessity for the show's production. The Vulcan language has been spoken in some of the movies at least (haven't seen all the series), and of course human actors were required to speak it and so it contains no non-pronounceable sounds. Thus there is a conflict set up in the canon here.

Comment: If you compare with TOS (where Commander Spock is referred to in non-formal situations as "Mr Spock"), TNG (where Lieutenant Worf - Son of Mogh, no surname - is referred to in non-formal situations as either "Mr Worf" or "Worf"), or DS9 (where Lieutenant Commander Eddington is referred to in non-formal situations as "Mr Eddington"), and combine that with the "no surnames for Vulcans" then calling him "Tuvok" or "Mr Tuvok" is consistent in-universe and can be assumed the correct form for Starfleet - and a *Research and Exporation fleet* rather than a Military fleet would likely be more relaxed.

Comment: @Chronocidal Don't forget Mr. Data.

Comment: "Mr" is an appropriate title for naval officers when addressed by a commanding officer. Although that wouldn't explain all the times Neelix called him Mr. Tuvok.

Comment: Neelix isn't Starfleet, so he has no obligation to use any Starfleet regulations when addressing Tuvok unless someone specifically insisted on it.

Comment: @Philipp I believe Spock says he has a *first* name, but it can't be pronounced. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23152/what-is-spocks-full-name

Comment: @Cadence In "This Side of Paradise" Leila says Spock never told her if he had another name; Spock says: "you couldn't pronounce it."  In "Journey to Babel" Kirk calls Amanda :Mrs. Sarek" and she says: "Amanda.  I'm afraid you couldn't pronounce the Vulcan name."  Thus it is probable that Spock has one or two other names that are very hard for humans to pronounce.  http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/25.htm  http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/44.htm

Comment: @The_Sympathizer -  What do you mean by "THE Vulcan language"?  Vulcan probably once had hundreds or thousands of languages, and the modern Vulcan government might be more like an Empire with many languages than a nation with one language.  There were many languages in the Roman Empire, and Roman aristocrats were bilingual in Latin and Greek.  In the Ottoman and Mughal Empires the court language was Persian, the (Muslim) religious language Arabic, & the army language Turkish, and there were hundreds of native languages.  So why shouldn't Vulcans be multilingual?  - Continued.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer - Continued.  If modern Vulcans are multilingual, why shouldn't their few lines in Vulcan languages in the movies be in one or more languages which are easy for humans to say, especially when speaking around humans, while every Vulcan in the movies knew at least one other language which would have been very hard for humans to pronounce.  Thus it may be customary for Vulcans to have names in different languages, some names in languages humans can speak easily, and some names in languages almost impossible for humans to pronounce.