# Do Vulcans Have Last Names?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

Do Vulcans have last names? I don't recall Spock or his father Sarek having a last name and I was wondering if Vulcans have last names.

Comment: Possible dupe of [What is Spock's full name?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23152/what-is-spocks-full-name)

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. What about Sarek or the rest of the Vulcan race?

Comment: This Vulcan has a last name. Are you excluding him?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to "Journey to Babel" (TOS), Vulcans did possess family names, although they were pronounceable by Humans only after many years of practice. They are not actually spoken or written in the episode. AFAIK, no canonical source has actually explicitly given a Vulcan family name. In TOS episode "This Side of Paradise" Spock is asked if he has another name, to which he replies, "You couldn't pronounce it."